# How to assign Roads Name or Roads Number to Lighting Poles point Layer along the Road?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

1)I have the Roads layer which contains the roads name and roads number
2)I have the Lighting Pole as a point layer contains the lighting pole voltage and power
3)I want to assign or link each roads name to its related lighting poles

I can do it manually but I need to do it in a faster way using ArcMap.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. In order to be answerable, questions here need to not only state the goal, but also detail what has been done toward accomplishing that hoal, and a specific problem which has been encountered. Please [Edit] the question to state the exact software in use, and what problem you have encountered. If you are coding a solution, we will need a snippet of code where the error occurs and the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the best tool would be a [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm). The tool will allow you to join attribute tables based on location or other geometric properties.

If the point and line layers don't intersect, your best Match Option would be 'Within a distance.'

Hopefully this helps!